# What are shmpages in laymans terms?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, shared-memory

What exactly are `shmpages` in the grand scheme of kernel and memory terminology. If I'm hitting a `shmpages` limit, what does that mean?

*I'm also curious if this applies to more than linux*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

User mode processes can use Interprocess Communication (IPC) to communicate with each other, the fastest method of achieving this is by using shared memory pages (`shmpages`).
This happens for example if `banshee` plays music and `vlc` plays a video, both processes have to access `pulseaudio` to output some sound.

Try to find out more about shared memory configuration and usage with some of the following commands:

Display the shared memory configuration:

```
sysctl kernel.shm{max,all,mni}
```

By default (Linux 2.6) this should output:

```
kernel.shmmax = 33554432
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmni = 4096
```

`shmmni` is the maximum number of allowed shared memory segments, `shmmax` is the allowed size of a shared memory segment (32 MB) and `shmall` is the maximum total size of all segments (displayed as pages, translates to 8 GB)

The currently used shared memory:

```
grep Shmem /proc/meminfo
```

If enabled by the distribution:

```
ls -l /dev/shm
```

`ipcs` is a great tool to find out more about IPC usage:

```
ipcs -m
```

will output the shared memory usage, you can see the allocated segments with the corresponding sizes.

```
ipcs -m -i <shmid>
```

shows more information about a specified segment including the PID of the process creating (cpid) and the last (lpid) using it.

`ipcrm` can remove shared memory segments (but be aware that those are only get removed if no other processes are attached to them, see the nattach column in `ipcs -m`).

```
ipcrm -m <shmid>
```

Running out of shared memory could be a program heavily using a lot of shared memory, a program which does not detach the allocated segments properly, modified `sysctl` values, ...

This is not Linux specific and also applies to (most) UNIX systems (shared memory first appeared in [CB UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CB_UNIX)).

Comment: A nitpick: use this command to find the currently used shared memory instead: `grep Shmem /proc/meminfo` This prevents a **UUC** (Useless Use of Cat ...)

Comment: Wow, great detailed answer, lots of little gems here :D

Comment: so what is `shmpages` compared to `kernel.shm{max,all,mni}` ?